# Deriving the SVD from the eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

If $A$ is a rectangular matrix of dimensions $m\times n$, then $S_L=AA^T$ and $S_R=A^TA$ are square symmetric matrices. Hence, using the eigendecompostion we can write
$$
S_L=AA^T=U\Lambda_{S_L} U^T
$$
and
$$
S_R=A^TA=V\Lambda_{S_R} V^T
$$
Where, $U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $S_L=AA^T$ and $V$ is the matrix of eigenvectors of $S_R=A^TA$ and $\Lambda_{S_L}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $AA^T$ and $\Lambda_{S_R}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A^TA$.

My question is how can we go from this result to singular value decomposition which says
$$
A=U\sqrt{\Lambda}V^T
$$
?

Comment: You are mistake. $S_L$ and $S_R$ are symmetric and not transposes of one another

Comment: ohh, i feel so stupid. $(AA^T)^T=AA^T$ and not $A^TA$, so this means we cannot derive SVD from EVD?

Comment: but still $\Lambda_{S_L}=\Lambda_{S_R}$ how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that $U$ and $V$ are chosen independently from two different, but related, spectral decompositions. To ensure that they are compatible in the sense that $A = U\Sigma V^T$, one has to choose one basis from the spectral decomposition, then construct the other from $A$.

For example, let $A^TA = V\Lambda V^T$, then notice that $AV = U\Lambda^{1/2} $, so $U$ is *uniquely* defined as $U = AV\Lambda^{-1/2}$. This argument works the same way when $A$ is not of full rank by using the pseudo-inverse of $\Lambda^{1/2}$, which can be defined without the SVD for diagonal matrices.

Comment: Ok, so this means, we dont find $U$ and $V$ separately from $AA^T$ and $A^TA$, but first we find $V$ then find $U$?

Comment: But what if we did calculated $U$ as the matrix containing eigenvectors of $AA^T$ in its columns and $V$ as the matrix containing eigenvectors of $A^TA$? And then took the top $k$ common, positive and non-zero eigenvalues from $\lambda_L$ and $\lambda_R$ and then took square root of them and placed as diagonals in $\Sigma$ square matrix 
$$
$$

Comment: $$
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & \sigma_2 & \dots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \dots & \sigma_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and chose only top k columns from U and V as well

Comment: In the case where the eigenspace is 1-dimensional, the corresponding columns of $U$ and $V$ would be off by some phase. This is because they are only unique in the spectral decomposition up to a phase. In the case of a higher dimensional eigenspace, I believe there would be more non-uniqueness as you would need to know how one basis maps into the other through $A$.